# How to place an Admob ads bottom center of the screen?(Using java code to place.)

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

I used this code to place my admob ads, but these code will show the ads on top left of the screen, How to place the ads bottom center of the screen?  please help :)

```
mAdView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "xxxxx");
FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.game_layout);
layout.addView(mAdView);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams adsParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.);
mAdView.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Height and Width layout Params for the FrameLayout should be FILL_PARENT. By Default it consider the height layout Param as WRAP_CONTENT and because of that even you have set the GRAVITY to BOTTOM your ads displayed on TOP.
SET the Layout Params as I said.

Comment: Hi Rahul, Thank you for your answer. I don't know which functions should I use to set these Params.  I use     <com.google.ads.AdView 
     android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        ads:adUnitId="xxxxx"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        />    xml layout to set ads.    can you give me some code to set ads using java code ?

Comment: Thank you Rahul again :) I used this following code to place admob ads in java code:
 

 mAdView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "xxxx");
  FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);

  FrameLayout.LayoutParams adsParams =new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
    android.view.Gravity.BOTTOM|android.view.Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
  layout.addView(mAdView, adsParams );
  mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

Comment: Before I answer, you got the Code.

Comment: this doesn't center horizontaly for me if you view in landscape :(

Answer (score 4):

You can also use

```
mAdView.setX([float x]);
mAdView.sety([float y]);
```

to set the position of Your ads.

Answer (score 1):

```
adView = new AdView(Cocos2dxActivity.this, AdSize.SMART_BANNER, "mediationId");
adView.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: above code is simple and more clear format to call and display on bottom position of screen. thanks

Comment: You just repeated some similar code the questioner already wrote in his question. And this code did not work.